How to Deploy Remix apps with Nx monorepo (2 app in 1 repo)
I am having some problem with deployment technique our old team member is using,
the deployment to EC2 with docker is not going well,
and we are facing a total dead end!
are there any other way to deploy NX monorepo with 2 app
of remix apps like this one:
https://github.com/Mattral/CoreAppTest

That one is cloned from the original codebase.
The deployment should be on EC2 but failed so I even tried vercel deployment but it is not working for monorepo.
